# Keras custom loss function returns Value Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using a custom loss function in [google TFT](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/tft) model.

```
def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):
     tupl = np.shape(y_actual)
     flag = tf.compat.v1.math.is_nan(y_actual)
     y_actual = y_actual[tf.compat.v1.math.logical_not(flag)]
     y_pred = y_pred[tf.compat.v1.math.logical_not(flag)]
     tensordiff = tf.compat.v1.math.reduce_sum(
                             tf.compat.v1.math.square(y_actual-y_pred))

     if len(tupl) >= 2:      
          tensordiff /= tupl[0]       
     if len(tupl) >= 3: 
          tensordiff /= tupl[1]      
     if len(tupl) >= 4:    
          tensordiff /= tupl[2]
        
     return tensordiff
```

I am able to run the code and train the model with a standard loss functions but when I use my custom loss function I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:445
          make_tensor_proto raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE:

Reran with below loop code

```
def custom_lossGCF1(y_actual,y_pred):
        tupl = np.shape(y_actual)
        tensordiff = tf.compat.v1.math.reduce_sum(tf.compat.v1.math.square(y_actual-y_pred))

        for x in range(min(len(tupl),4)-1):
          tensordiff = tf.compat.v1.math.divide_no_nan(tensordiff,tupl[x])

        return tensordiff
```

and still encountering below error:

any suggestions?

```
alueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-99-3fb23687b2d6>:1076 custom_lossGCF1  *
        tensordiff = tf.compat.v1.math.divide_no_nan(tensordiff, tupl[x])
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1463 div_no_nan
        y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, name="y", dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1566 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:339 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:265 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:283 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:445 make_tensor_proto
        raise ValueError("None values not supported.")

    ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `if` statements in your loss function as it has no gradient.
Try replacing it with this code. This loop serves the same function as your `if` statements

```
def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):
   
        tupl = np.shape(y_actual)
        flag = tf.compat.v1.math.is_nan(y_actual)
        y_actual = y_actual[tf.compat.v1.math.logical_not(flag)]
        y_pred = y_pred[tf.compat.v1.math.logical_not(flag)]
        tensordiff = tf.compat.v1.math.reduce_sum(tf.compat.v1.math.square(y_actual-y_pred))
        
        for x in range(min(len(tupl),4)-1):
                tensordiff /= tupl[x]
        
        return tensordiff
```

Comment: thanks! It's -1 instead of -2 but thanks for the good suggestion

Comment: @Gamecocks20 thank you for finding out the error in my code, I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have `if` statement inside you loss function, the `if` has no gradient, just think about what's the derivative of `if`.